# How to use SqlCacheDependency?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, caching, service-broker

I need to implement SqlCacheDependency for a table which will depend on this query:
`SELECT Nickname FROM dbo.[User]`.

I have created a method for this purpose:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetNicknamesFromCache()
    {
        const String cacheValueName = "Nicknames";

        var result = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheValueName) as List<String>;
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = _repository.GetAllNicknames();

            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RepositoryContext"].ConnectionString;
            var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nickname FROM dbo.[User]", sqlConnection);
            var sqlDependency = new SqlCacheDependency(sqlCommand);

            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheValueName, result, sqlDependency);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

But when I run my application it doesn't work.
I checked the list of subscribers (`sys.dm_qn_subscriptions` table) and there was no records.

I investigated much time and have already tried various solutions but they doesn't work for me:

- use trusted connection and set some permissions for public role:

  `GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO public`
  `GRANT CREATE QUEUE TO public`
  `GRANT CREATE SERVICE TO public`
  `GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO public`
  `GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::dbo.[User] TO public`
  `GRANT RECEIVE ON QueryNotificationErrorsQueue TO public`
- use 'sa' login for connection
- use aspnet_regsql.exe (`aspnet_regsql.exe -S localhost -E -ed -d TestTable -et -t User`)
- add configuration to system.webServer in web.config:

  `<caching>`
    `<sqlCacheDependency enabled="true">`
      `<databases>`
        `<add name="Tmpl" pollTime="5000" connectionStringName="RepositoryContext"/>`
      `</databases>`
    `</sqlCacheDependency>`
  `</caching>`
- put the SqlDependency.Start() into the Global.asax Application_Start event
- run at different instances of sql server (SQL Server 2008 Express, SQL Server 2008)

But It didn't help. It still doesn't work.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have already found solution.

At first check whether Service Broker is enabled for your table and enable it if needed:

```
SELECT name, is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '<databaseName>'

ALTER DATABASE <databaseName> SET enable_broker WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Next create in SQL Server new role `sql_dependency_role`, grant permissions to it and grant role to user:

```
EXEC sp_addrole 'sql_dependency_role'

GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE to sql_dependency_role
GRANT CREATE QUEUE to sql_dependency_role
GRANT CREATE SERVICE to sql_dependency_role
GRANT REFERENCES on CONTRACT::[http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification] to sql_dependency_role
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO sql_dependency_role
GRANT SELECT to sql_dependency_role
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO sql_dependency_role
GRANT RECEIVE ON QueryNotificationErrorsQueue TO sql_dependency_role

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'sql_dependency_role', '<userName>'
```

After that add C# code for working with `SqlCacheDependency` or `SqlDependency` (mostly the same way).

I have changed my method and now it looks like this:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetNicknamesFromCache()
    {
        const String cacheValueName = "Nicknames";

        var result = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheValueName) as List<String>;
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = _repository.GetAllNicknames();

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_config.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlDependency.Start(_config.ConnectionString);
                var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nickname FROM dbo.[User]", connection);
                var dependency = new SqlCacheDependency(command);
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheValueName, result, dependency);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Now it works fine.

Don't forget invoke `SqlDependency.Start` method before creating `SqlCacheDependency` or `SqlDependency` and execute your command at the end.

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the connection open as you've done here or can you close/dispose it?

Comment: Answering my own question above - it is necessary to keep this connection open so the service broker can send those notifications.  Which makes this a bit harder to design around if you have many cache entries that need to be refreshed.