# SqlCacheDependency multiple / bulk updates

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to understand how SqlCacheDependency works in a bulk update situation. 
I understand how to set it up and if I make one row change in the database my cache becomes invalid.

My question is if I do a bulk update on a table that has 100 rows

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Col = 1
```

**Question**

Do I get 100 invalidate notifications, or is it smart enough to know the data changed and only 1 notification is sent, thus it only invalidates the data once?

I'm using something similar to this:[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16490578/320168)

My concern is that if it invalidates over and over again then it will be hitting the database 100 times to get the fresh data and I would have to think of an alternative strategy.

Regards DotnetShadow