# How to pull from database only when data has changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a car website using C#/MVC 4.5, and I need to find a more dynamic way to pull data from the database. More specifically to dynamically refresh data.

So far I have figured out 2 ways of pulling data, however they are both unacceptable for different reasons:

Car.cs pulls data from the database, based on an int parameter.

```
    // CarContorller.cs
    public class CarController : Controller
    {
        public static Car Car1 = new Car(1);
    }

    // FrontPage.cshtml
    @using CarSite.Models
    @{
        Car C = new Car(1);
    }
    <div class="car-name">
        Car Name From Model (Database): @C.Name
        Car Name From Controller (Memory): @CarSite.Controllers.CarController.Car1.Name <br>
    </div>
```

So here's my predicament:

- **Pulling from the Model** forces data to be refreshed each time the site is loaded. So if I have 3 cars, and 1000 visitors per day, data is being pulled 3000 times per day, even if it's the same data over and over again.
- **Pulling from the Controller** allows data to only be pulled once, but if it changes, it is not reflected until the site is reset.

Is it possible to refresh the Controller data only when it has changed? If so, how is this accomplished? If not, what can I do to prevent so many data pulls?

Comment: Let use asp.net cache. Cache that linked to Database will be notifed changed to refresh its data. :D

Comment: i guess adding `DateTime LastTimeModified` in your controller is out of question ?

Comment: @hungndv can you expand on that? Do you know of an article that may describe it more?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is **Caching with Sql Dependency**.

There are quite a few examples on this, I recall reading this one when I was learning about it:

http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/sqlcachedependency.aspx

I also found this SO post, which you may find useful:

[How to use SqlCacheDependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383513/how-to-use-sqlcachedependency)

Comment: My connection string needs to use a dsn, System.Data.SqlClient does not work with dsn's. Do you know of anything similar that would work with dsn's?