# How to wrap or observe using SQL CLR types

Tags: sql-server, observable, sqlclr, sqldependency, database-trigger

I am aware of DB triggers and not seeking that option. I am wondering if its possible to observe DB tables with a reader from the middle ware.

Question - is it possible to get a observable wrapper using the SQL CLR types in C# on a Database table, for e.g. I have a table of tickets, how do I watch the table.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If I understand your question correctly, the answer is no.

Comment: @srutzky I have quite a few Tables (and POCO,s) I am trying to get changeNotifications when something happens in the database (edits) to the table. I thought SQL CLR had hooks for those change notifications. Just looking for the easiest way to get those changes to the tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SQLCLR does not provide any special means of doing this.

*The* best, most appropriate, *and only* way to accomplish getting notifications of table modifications is through Triggers. That is what they are meant to do. You can capture data changes via DML Triggers (for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` operations), and you can capture structural changes via DDL Triggers (for `ALTER TABLE`, `CREATE / ALTER / DROP TRIGGER`, and `CREATE / DROP INDEX` operations).

You can create either type of Trigger using either pure T-SQL or using SQLCLR, though the SQLCLR option doesn't afford much benefit over T-SQL besides being able to access the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables via Dynamic SQL. The other reason to use a SQLCLR Trigger would be if you just need all rows of data from one or both of those pseudo-tables for a single operation. Else you could just call a SQLCLR User-Defined Function in a T-SQL Trigger if you needed to handle something on a per-row basis.

Remember, Triggers are part of the Transaction that is internally created (if no Transaction is currently active) when the DML operation starts. This way any changes made by the Trigger can be rolled-back if the DML operation ultimately fails.

If you want very light-weight notifications, you can do one of the following, but keep in mind that both will side-step the Transaction (i.e. cannot take back notification of an operation that fails to complete) and so can easily result in false-positives (i.e. notifications of modifications that never committed):

1. Send emails via [sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx). This is asynchronous so should not adversely impact performance. But you do need to format the full data modification report as a string (perhaps as HTML?) in the trigger rather than attaching the results of a query since the query for the email won't have access to the pseudo-tables.
2. Use SQLCLR to dump desired info to a text file. You just need to be careful to allow for multiple, concurrent write-requests to the file, else concurrent DML statements will be negatively impacted.

---

A quick note about Query Notifications since the question was tagged with **SqlDependency**:

Query Notifications are not really helpful here. In addition to a list of restrictions on what queries are eligible for Query Notifications, they only indicate that the result set of a particular query has changed. So even if you set up simple notifications for `SELECT * FROM table;`, it won't tell you *what* changed specifically (i.e. the rows in the `INSERTED` and/or `DELETED` pseudo-tables available in Triggers). Still, if you are interested in reading up on them, here are two helpful links:

- [Working with Query Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx)
- [Query Notifications in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx)

Comment: thanks - BTW, I want to minimize the code so its clean to read and easy for me :)  is there a way to turn on notification from the db to the tables inside my middleware when I setup the POCO or entity models, or statup?

Comment: @transformer Yer welcome :-). And not sure what you mean. Are you actually going to use Query Notifications, or do you mean creating Triggers?

Comment: All 3 options in the query notification link (2) seem to be very similar. For me either option would work, as far having some hooks exposed in the CLR, so I dont have worry about touching the DB. After searching some more for notifications inside the middleware -- looks like there is some [wiring up to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383513/how-to-use-sqlcachedependency) to get it working. Its sad that trackable entities are not that robust, _wonder if that EF would provide change tracking option by default at the model level_.